# Subgroup membership in hyperbolic groups and determining hyperbolicity

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-groups

I have a set of two (not necessarily entirely related) questions about hyperbolic groups - I'll ask them as one question since they seem related enough and I have a feeling someone who knows the answer to one of the questions might know the answer to the other.  Sorry for my ignorance on the subject - any pointers to references would be appreciated. OK, here are the questions:

(1) Is there an algorithm to determine if a given finitely-presented group is hyperbolic?

(2) Given a finitely-generated subgroup $H$ in a given finitely-presented group $G$ and a word $w$ in the generators of $G$, is there an algorithm to determine if $w \in H$?  What about the same question but restricted to finite index $H$?  For the case where $H=1$, I am aware of the solvability of the word problem for hyperbolic groups, but I don't know about the more general case.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For $(1)$, see [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238740/verify-that-a-group-is-hyperbolic-via-computer-algebra), and other posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to (1) is no, but it is possible to verify hyperbolicity (see the link in Dietrich Burde's comment).

(2) is no in general - this is called the *Generalized Word Problem*. The word problem in $G$ is equivalent to the case $H=1$. As you remarked, the word problem is solvable in hyperbolic groups, but there are examples in which the generalized word problem is not solvable.

Such examples can be constructed using a very simple technique due to Rips. Starting with an arbitrary finitely presented group $Q$, you can construct a finite presented group $G$ that satifies arbitrarily strong small-cancellation conditions, and which has a finitely generated normal subgroup $H$ with $G/H \cong Q$.

The answer is yes for subgroups that are known to be of finite index - you can do it by coset enumeration - but of course the problem of determining whether $|G:H|$ is finite is unsolvable.

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer!  I had a few hopefully simple questions/clarifications.  Why is there no such algorithm for testing if a group is hyperbolic?  Also, is determining if the index is finite also unsolvable in a hyperbolic group?

Comment: Hyperbolicity is a *Markov property* and the Adian-Rabin theorem says that there is no decision process to decide whether a given finitely presented group has such a property. There is a proof in Thm 12.2 of Rotman's "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups", 4th edition. You cannot decide finiteness of $|G:H|$ even for hyperbolic groups $G$. If you could then you could use the Rips construction to solve this problem in an arbitrary finitely presented group $Q$.

Comment: Thank you very much - I always learn a lot from your answers.